# firebase database concurrent adding of same item

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about firebase database concurrent adding of same item.
I have an android client app and firebase realtime database.

In my database I will have a "nomenclature" of areas:

```
  area1, area2, area3, area4 etc..
```

Users should be able to add some of these areas to an "active list" in the database.

```
 e.g: area2, area5, area10
```

So if two or more users try to add the same area to this active list at the same time would it be a problem?
I think that the databse requests should be sequential but I want to be sure what is the right approach it this situation.
Maybe some transaction and some check.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining how Firebase is involved here.  I think it would help if you edited the question to show the code you're working with that illustrates the problem at hand, along with any data in the database you're working with.

Comment: Doug is right, although I already suspect that your solution will have to be based on [using transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) and [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Comment: I do not have any code yet.
I'm still on "idea" phase.
Thank you for the link :) I think that's exactly what I need :)